# "Unfolding" a String

Tags: php, loops, permutation, combinations, combinatorics

I have a set of strings, each string has a variable number of segments separated by pipes (`|`), e.g.:

```
$string = 'abc|b|ac';
```

Each segment with more than one char should be expanded into all the possible one char combinations, for 3 segments the following "algorithm" works wonderfully:

```
$result = array();
$string = explode('|', 'abc|b|ac');

foreach (str_split($string[0]) as $i)
{
    foreach (str_split($string[1]) as $j)
    {
        foreach (str_split($string[2]) as $k)
        {
            $result[] = implode('|', array($i, $j, $k)); // more...
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
$result = array('a|b|a', 'a|b|c', 'b|b|a', 'b|b|c', 'c|b|a', 'c|b|c');
```

Obviously, for more than 3 segments the code starts to get extremely messy, since I need to add (and check) more and more inner loops. I tried coming up with a dynamic solution but I can't figure out how to generate the correct combination for all the segments (individually and as a whole). I also looked at some combinatorics source code but I'm unable to combine the different combinations of my segments.

I appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: How important is the order? Or are you OK with just having all the combinations being generated?

Comment: @NullUserException: The order of each segment is critical, the order by which each char appears in that specific segment is irrelevant, as long as no duplicates are generated ofc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409533/unfolding-a-string/7409651#7409651) to the rescue (you might need to tweak a bit to cover edge cases, but it works):

```
function explodinator($str) {
    $segments = explode('|', $str);
    $pieces = array_map('str_split', $segments);

    return e_helper($pieces);
}

function e_helper($pieces) {

    if (count($pieces) == 1)
        return $pieces[0];

    $first = array_shift($pieces);
    $subs = e_helper($pieces);

    foreach($first as $char) {
        foreach ($subs as $sub) {
            $result[] = $char . '|' . $sub;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(explodinator('abc|b|ac'));
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a|b|a
    [1] => a|b|c
    [2] => b|b|a
    [3] => b|b|c
    [4] => c|b|a
    [5] => c|b|c
)
```

As seen on [ideone](http://ideone.com/BUUns).

Comment: Haha, +1 just for the recursive link. ;) Thanks, I'll dig into that in the morning.

Comment: Nicely done, works flawlessly. Obrigado! =) @stereofrog: Good catch.

Comment: Impressive, I didn't expect it to be faster than the code I gave when I first saw it ...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for recursive programming! :P
I first looked at this and thought it was going to be a on-liner (and probably is in perl).
There are other non-recursive ways (enumerate all combinations of indexes into segments then loop through, for example) but I think this is more interesting, and probably 'better'.

```
 $str = explode('|', 'abc|b|ac');
 $strlen = count( $str );
 $results = array();

 function splitAndForeach( $bchar , $oldindex, $tempthread) {
     global $strlen, $str, $results;
     $temp = $tempthread;
     $newindex = $oldindex + 1;

     if ( $bchar != '') { array_push($temp, $bchar ); }

     if ( $newindex <= $strlen ){
         print "starting foreach loop on string '".$str[$newindex-1]."' \n";

         foreach(str_split( $str[$newindex - 1] ) as $c) {
             print "Going into next depth ($newindex) of recursion on char $c \n";
             splitAndForeach( $c , $newindex, $temp);
         }

     } else {

        $found = implode('|', $temp);
        print "Array length (max recursion depth) reached, result: $found \n";

        array_push( $results, $found );
        $temp = $tempthread;
        $index = 0;
        print "***************** Reset index to 0 *****************\n\n";
     }
 }

 splitAndForeach('', 0, array() );
 print "your results: \n";
 print_r($results);
```

Comment: Dammit, this was unanswered when I started writing that but I went off and checked emails before I finished!  Oh well, hope it helps clarify things (it could look a lot smaller and neater, but I think being expressive helps show something).

Comment: See the answer by NullUserException.  Mine is a fairly 'pure' version of the code block the OP was intending to recursively process, but this is less efficient than the code in his answer (I timed both running on the console with larger strings).  If speed is important, use his, if readability/customization are more important and my code makes sense, use that.

Answer (score 1):

You could have two arrays: the alternatives and a *current counter*.

```
$alternatives = array(array('a', 'b', 'c'), array('b'), array('a', 'c'));
$counter = array(0, 0, 0);
```

Then, in a loop, you increment the "last digit" of the counter, and if that is equal to the number of alternatives for that position, you reset that "digit" to zero and increment the "digit" left to it. This works just like counting with decimal numbers.

The string for each step is built by concatenating the `$alternatives[$i][$counter[$i]]` for each digit.

You are finished when the "first digit" becomes as large as the number of alternatives for that digit.

Example: for the above variables, the counter would get the following values in the steps:

```
0,0,0
0,0,1
1,0,0 (overflow in the last two digit)
1,0,1
2,0,0 (overflow in the last two digits)
2,0,1
3,0,0 (finished, since the first "digit" has only 3 alternatives)
```

Comment: Can you show a working example? This is confusing me a little bit.

Comment: Maybe this example helps a bit. I didn't write the example in PHP, since I don't know that language well enough.

Comment: Basically he's counting through all the possible ways of counting char positions in the three groups and using those to index into the actual arrays to build up the char segments.  I wouldn't exactly recommend it, but its an interesting alternative (I suspect it is less efficient).